# SQL Server 2012: Backup restore from a compressed backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to restore a database from the backup (`.bak`) file which is [saved] inside a `ZIP` file, but not been successful so far. However, I am able to restore it after extracting from the `ZIP` file.

This [MS page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719(v=sql.110).aspx) says every edition of SQL Server 2008 and later can restore a compressed backup with the following restrictions.

> Restrictions: The following restrictions apply to compressed backups:
>
> 1. Compressed and uncompressed backups cannot co-exist in a media set.
> 2. Previous versions of SQL Server cannot read compressed backups.
> 3. NTbackups cannot share a tape with compressed SQL Server backups.

I do not clearly understand the first restriction. Could someone please clarify/elaborate this?

I have done the following steps:

1. Taken a backup on a staging SQL Server [`MyTestDB.bak`]; Compressed it (by Right Click > Send To - Compressed(zipped) folder); Now, named it as `MyTestDB.ZIP`
2. FTP'd the `ZIP` file to local development SQL Server and trying to restore it from the `ZIP` file. But the database name is not available to backup.

Both SQL Server versions are exactly same.

> SQL Servers Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)-Standard Edition (64-bit)

[image: When tried to restore from ZIP file]

Would the usage of term 'compressed backup' for the backup files saved inside ZIP files is correct or Is this need to be backed up in a different way so it can be called as a compressed backup?

3. However, if I select the `.bak` file after extracting it from the `ZIP` file it all works fine.

[image: When tried to restore from .bak file]

I am not sure where I am going wrong? I can simply extract the backup and restore it without any problem, but would like to know the cause why it is not working, as it would have been a much better solution to just back up it from the `ZIP` itself.

Comment: SQL engine use its own compression method while backing up. I guess pages/extents are compressed not a BAK file. So those restrictions are not ZIP-file related.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231019.aspx describes how to configure backup compression within SQL Server.

Comment: And yes - 2008 was a first edition, where standard edition was able to use compression on backup.

Comment: "Compression" doesn't mean "ZIP compression". Compressed backups are still regular .bak files, just in another format. SQL Server cannot read backups from ZIP files, and if your backup is compressed, there is no need to put it in a ZIP file as it will not significantly compress further.

Comment: From my experience - internal compression will do 1:4 ratio, external compression (RAR) + no internal compression will do 1:10 ratio; BUT if internal compression is used RAR won't compress any better; so for the best ratio use no internal compression + RAR

Comment: For some reasons you may want to use NTFS compression - BAK without internal compression will be compressed by NTFS with ratio 1:4 - and this is real time compression/decompression so you do not need to unpack your file first. But I also have bad experiences with NTFS compression - whole file system went slow after time.

Comment: @huhu78: Thanks for your valuable comments. I do not clearly understand a restriction on MS website: "Compressed and uncompressed backups cannot co-exist in a media set", could you please clarify?

Comment: You can "save" 2 or more backups into one BAK file - so I guess you cannot mix compressed and uncompressed into common BAK file.

Comment: What's more - compressing transaction log backups is good for log shipping over Internet solution (less to transfer); But for long-time archiving it's batter to have a good compress ratio (so no SQL compression + RAR); RAR can also slice backup into smaller files (good for retransmission over Internet) and can also do RAID like recovery volumes or additional checksums. So you can restore even if RAR file is broken a bit (additional checksum) or if some files are missing (recovery volumes).

Comment: @huhu78: Thank you very much for your comments, very informative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backup compression is something different.

You specify this when you configure or start the backup and you then get a backup file that contains compressed data, as opposed to it containing uncompressed data if you don't enable compression.

SQL Server is not able to use a zip file, while the backup file is certainly compressed, it is not a "compressed backup" that this refers to.

So yes, you need to extract the backup file before restoring from it.

If you want to learn how to make compressed backups correctly, check out this page full of links to related material:

- [Configure Backup Compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231019.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I do not clearly understand a restriction on MS website: "Compressed and uncompressed backups cannot co-exist in a media set", Would you mind to clarify/elaborate, please ?